# How to refresh java project in eclipse programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, local

I am generating properties dinamicaly in code and when I need to set bundle to some locale, I am getting error where compiler say that he cant find properties file generated. Project is not refreshed yet then. I tried with 10s thread sleep, same story.
When I manualy copy that generated properties in src, whole thing works perfectly, but that is not dinamicaly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you dynamically generating properties? Do you run a command line program? Ant target? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: Where are the generated properties located?

Comment: I am creating new file with File, BufferedWriter and PrintWriter. They are gerated well, no problem with that

Comment: They are located in project folder, maybe when I could put them in src. But dont know how to do that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only code in an Eclipse plugin can refresh projects programatically (using `IResource.refreshLocal`).

You can set the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' option in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace' page to get Eclipse to look for your updates.